# Find the solution (depending on $\lambda$) of the equation $x(t) = \lambda \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(t-s)x(s) ds $.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, laplace-transform, integral-equations

The question is as follows:

Find in $C[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $L_p[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, for $1 \leq p \leq +\infty$, the solution (depending on $\lambda$) of the integral equation of the First kind
$$x(t) = \lambda \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(t-s)x(s) ds $$.

$\textbf{Some idea:}$

As we see $\int \cos(t-s)x(s) ds$ looks like the convolution product of $k(s,t)=\cos(t-s)$ and $x(s)$. So maybe we can somehow transform this integral such that be able to use the Laplace Transform. (Because we know that $L[k \star x] = L[k]L[x]$, and it will make the job easier.) But I really do not know how to solve such equations!

Can someone give some idea on how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can differentiate under the integral sign twice to get $x''(t) = -\lambda x(t)$

Comment: You say "of the first kind". It means you have been exposed to Fredholm theory, isn't it ?

Comment: @Dylan Thanks! But do we also have initial conditions here? Can we solve this differential equation without initial conditions?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks! I added that to the question. I thought maybe will be helpful.

Comment: You can get the general solution and plug it back into the integral equation to obtain the constants.

Comment: @Dylan Thanks! You mean $x(t) = c_1\sin \sqrt{\lambda}t + c_2 \cos \sqrt{\lambda}t$? I mean can we find this without knowing $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$?

Comment: I'm saying, try plugging that into the original equation and integrate to see what you get. May you'll find something, maybe you won't. I'm just making suggestions.